# set the reminder on Event through apex

Tags: apex, trigger, event

I'm trying to set the reminders time, on Event, 15 minutes before the startDatetime, and if the event is an allday event, I want to set a reminder 15 minutes before the 9:00 o'clock. How can I do it through apex code?  Could you give me a hint please?

Comment: allDay event does not store time part in StartDateTime

Comment: But there is a field on the Event object called `ReminderDateTime`

Comment: You can post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you would want to do in your trigger is first generate a map from user id to timezone offset for future use.

```
map</*User*/Id,Integer> UserTimeZoneOffsets = new map<Id,Integer>();
for (User u : [SELECT Id, TimeZoneSidKey FROM USER]) 
    UserTimeZoneOffsets.put(u.Id,TimeZone.getTimeZone(u.TimeZoneSidKey).getOffset(system.now()));
```

Then loop through the events and for each individual event `e`:

1. Check to see if the Event is an All Day Event `e.IsAllDayEvent = TRUE`
2. If so, use the ActivityDate field to construct a new date time instance with the DateTime.newInstance() method and set that to be the value of the ReminderDateTime, remember to also account for different time zones.
   `e.ReminderDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(e.ActivityDate,Time.newInstance(8,45,0,0).addMilliseconds(UserTimeZoneOffsets.get(e.OwnerId)));`

   If not an all day event, the ReminderDateTime field could be set to be the StartDateTime minus 15 minutes. `e.ReminderDateTime = e.StartDateTime.addMinutes(-15)`
3. Set the reminder to fire. `e.IsReminderSet = TRUE`